# How to get access token from refresh token

Tags: ios, oauth-2.0, refresh, token

I'm trying to retrieve an oAuth 2.0 access token from a keychain item.

```
   myAuth = [GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch authForGoogleFromKeychainForName:keychainItemName
                                                                clientID:clientID
                                                            clientSecret:clientSecret];
```

It return to myAuth an object but it is not containing access_token, expires_in, token_type but only refresh_token. if i call myAuth.canAuthorize it return me YES but i can't authorize any request.

How ca I get an acces token back with my refresh token?

Thank by advance